# disable all functionality of an activity with adding transparent LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have an activity:

```
ActivityA
```

with xml:

```
RelativeLayout

    ButtonA

    FragmentA

    LinearLayout_Transparent
```

when the activity starts, LinearLayout_Transparent on top of all , but i can click the ButtonA, Touch the FragmentA and so on.

**Question** is: how to disable all functionality (ButtonA Click, Fragment touch) with **LinearLayout_Transparent**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the xml for LinearLayout_Transparent

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question completely. But from what I understood, I think the linear layout is annoying you. You can just resize the Linear layout to 0,0 or just change the visibility of Linear Layout.

Comment: when adding LinearLayout_Transparent i want to disable click the button, touch the fragment and so on. but LinearLayout_Transparent on top of all and we can click the button